# Apache-spark - Reading data from aws-s3 bucket with glacier objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-glacier

The scenario is this:

- I'm using `spark` to read an `s3-bucket`, where some objects (`parquet`) were transitioned to `glacier` storage class. **I'm not trying to read these objects**, but there is an error on `spark` using these kind of buckets (https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21797).

There is a workaround that "fix" this issue: https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21797?focusedCommentId=16140408&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16140408. But looking into the code: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16474/files, call's are still made and only skipping those files that raise an `IOException`. Is there any better way to config `Spark` to only load `Standard` objects on `s3-bucket`?.

Answer (score 0):

1. someone (you?) gets to fix https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14837 ; have s3a raise a specific exception when attempts to read glaciated data fails
2. then spark needs to recognise and skip that when it happens

I don't think S3's LIST call flags when an object is glaciated -so the filtering cannot be done during query planning/partitioning. It will be very expensive to call HEAD for each object at that point in the process.

Comment: I think that behavior (ignore files) is basically done by `spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles=true` (https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16474/files). One workaround is if we define the `schema` to load the data and apply a `.filter` (ie. by partitioned date or whatever identified - always standard objects). But, I'm looking for the optimal solution for this use case (s3 bucket with glacier objects -won't be used, but there are some of them on that bucket).